# Laravel creating cache files under different users and different permissions

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-filesystem

The server sometimes encounter permission errors. When checked the cache directory the cache files are being written under different users and permissions. I guess the issue is causing because of that. Why Laravel is writing caches under different users and permission? How to change the user to `www-data` ?

[image]

I'm using (https://github.com/grosv/laravel-passwordless-login) for creating passwordless login and the caches are written by this package.

Comment: Are there any Laravel commands being run from CLI?

Comment: @brombeer I've commands running from CLI which is schedule run. ```* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/www && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1```

Answer (score 1):

I thought the problem occurs like you said "This is actually Laravel creating file under multiple users & permission"

Today I change the user to execute the command in crontab

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/www && sudo -Hu www-data php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

That the cache data owner:group will be www-data:www-data.

It solve my problem that the same with you, I think it maybe an alternative solution to you.

Answer (score 0):

run this command

first

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage 
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache
```

then

```
sudo chmod -R 775 storage 

sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Comment: I already assigned permission like the above. This is actually Laravel creating file under multiple users & permission